# GridView RowUpdating can't get the new values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I was just testing if I will get the changed value out of the textbox when updating with no luck. I just cant get the new value. What am I doing wrong? I have tried numerous things. And this is the latest one. How can I get the updated new value to my label? When I click edit on the grid and change the value of the textbox and click update the label will just display the original value of the textbox.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    bindgrid();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label1.Text = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex]).Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bindgrid();
}
```

Comment: Have you debug the code, what value getting in the Label1?

Comment: It reads up there... "When I click edit on the grid and change the value of the textbox and click update the label will just display the original value of the textbox." So lets say there is "test" in the textbox originally and then I edit it to "asd" then click update. "test" will appear in label not "asd" as I would want to.

Comment: you have to save the value in the database and again bind the grid to the new datasource

Comment: You should save the value of **Label1** in the database in the **GridView1_RowUpdating** event before binding grid
In your code value is saving nowhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think when you push update link `Gridview` is binding again before taking new value. You must use `if(!IsPostBack)` before `GridView.DataBind()`.

Comment: Oh yea this is it. I instantly realized this was it when I saw your reply. This was one of those problems again that I didn't even think of before you mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

just set Enableviewstate property to false of gridview you can get new value.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ID="GridView6"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"
                EmptyDataText="No Record Found" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="ChangePage"
                OnRowCommand="RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView6_RowDataBound" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Why were you calling `GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex]` again when you already have the current row? Try use the row you already retrieved

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label1.Text = ((TextBox) row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
```

[Read more on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx)